# Filling empty months in a SQL query with data from previous records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to fill in months with data from previous months in a SQL query. I have a table which contains records recording rental of items. A record is only created in the table when an item is rented out or returned. I need a monthly overview of what each company (customer) needs to pay.

The table looks like this:

```
Companyname  itemID               logdate          costcalc 
Company A   VB004536    2015-11-10 16:41:25.000     false   
storage     VB004536    2015-10-27 16:15:44.000     false   
Company z   VB004536    2015-10-15 08:31:17.000     false   
Company A   VB004536    2015-09-24 08:47:56.000     false   
storage     VB004536    2015-09-03 11:34:45.000     false   
Company z   VB004536    2015-07-02 08:23:41.000     true    
storage     VB004536    2015-06-10 13:22:27.000     false
Company c   VB004536    2015-05-18 09:57:20.000     false   
Company c   VB004536    2015-01-19 14:01:49.000     false
```

My desired result is:

```
Companyname  itemID               logdate          costcalc 
Company A   VB004536    2015-11-10 16:41:25.000     false   
storage     VB004536    2015-10-27 16:15:44.000     false   
Company z   VB004536    2015-10-15 08:31:17.000     false   
Company A   VB004536    2015-09-24 08:47:56.000     false   
storage     VB004536    2015-09-03 11:34:45.000     false   
Company z   VB004536    2015-08-02 08:23:41.000     true    based on the prev row
Company z   VB004536    2015-07-02 08:23:41.000     true    
storage     VB004536    2015-06-10 13:22:27.000     false
Company c   VB004536    2015-05-18 09:57:20.000     false   
Company c   VB004536    2015-04-19 14:01:49.000     false   based on the prev row
Company c   VB004536    2015-03-19 14:01:49.000     false   based on the prev row
Company c   VB004536    2015-02-19 14:01:49.000     false   based on the prev row
Company c   VB004536    2015-01-19 14:01:49.000     false
```

So for example, `Company c` rented item `VB004536` on `2015-01-19` and it wasn't returned to storage until `2016-06-10`, then `Company z` rented it from `2015-07-02` etc.

I have tried queries like:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER OVER (PARTITION BY Companyname ORDER BY logdate DESC) AS rownum, 
       Companyname,
       logdate, 
       itemID,
       costcalc,  
       LAG(itemID,costcalc, 1,0) as prev_row
```

but `LAG` is not supported on SQL 2008 and also it would not fill in all the missing months with appropriate data.

I do not know how (or even if) this can be done and whether any way to achieve it will have sufficiently high performance as the dataset grows over time. Can anyone suggest a solution to get the output I require?

Comment: Can you please explain more on your expected result

Comment: You will most likely get a fair solution to the specific issue you have posted. However, if you have more date-range work to do you will find it useful to create a set of date data and date functions on top of what SQL provides. I faced similar issues years back and found the techniques in this blog a lifesaver. http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/01/02/56079.aspx

Comment: @TheGameiswar like what i need it for ?

Comment: @Vanquished Wombat thanks for the tip !

Comment: You have two problems: adding rows for "missing" months and then populating the values in those rows based on values in a row for a previous month (for the same item). There are quite a few questions on SO already which deal with both of these questions - you can solve the missing months issue with a Calendar table or perhaps a recursive CTE and the second issue can probably also be resolved with a CTE, self-joins or a subquery (if you can't use `LAG` on your SQL version). Have you tried searching for similar questions to help you?

Comment: @3N1GM4 gives good advice. The link I provided includes the calendar table concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a simplified `Months` table in lieu of a full calendar table:

```
CREATE TABLE Months (
    [Month] DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO Months
SELECT '2015-01-01'
UNION
SELECT '2015-02-01'
UNION
SELECT '2015-03-01'
UNION
SELECT '2015-04-01'
UNION
SELECT '2015-05-01'
UNION
SELECT '2015-06-01'
UNION
SELECT '2015-07-01'
UNION
SELECT '2015-08-01'
UNION
SELECT '2015-09-01'
UNION
SELECT '2015-10-01'
UNION
SELECT '2015-11-01'
UNION
SELECT '2015-12-01'
```

I believe this query gives your desired outcome:

```
SELECT ISNULL(l.ItemId,previous.ItemId) AS ItemId,
       ISNULL(l.LogDate,FORMAT(m.[Month],'yyyy-MM-') + FORMAT(previous.LogDate,'dd HH:mm:ss.000')) AS LogDate,
       ISNULL(l.CompanyName,previous.CompanyName) AS CompanyName,
       ISNULL(l.CostCalc,previous.CostCalc) AS CostCalc
FROM Months m
LEFT JOIN ItemLog l ON FORMAT(l.LogDate, 'MMM yyyy') = FORMAT(m.[Month], 'MMM yyyy')
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP 1 ItemId, LogDate, CompanyName, CostCalc
    FROM ItemLog prev
    WHERE prev.LogDate < m.[Month]
    ORDER BY prev.LogDate DESC
) previous
ORDER BY ISNULL(l.LogDate,FORMAT(m.[Month],'yyyy-MM-') + FORMAT(previous.LogDate,'dd HH:mm:ss.000')) DESC
```

If you have a variety of `ItemId` values in your table (as I suspect you do), you'll need to make some slight alterations, but this should at least show you one way this is possible as a starting point.

Comment: Hi thanks for the help I tried finding other solution then creating a calendar table. I unfortunately have no access to the database i can only read from it. because of this I was not allowed to create one thanks to you i was able to convence them. im very sorry i know this is not what SO is for but they forced my hand

Comment: There are other ways to achieve this without creating a calendar table - I can add an example if that would still be helpful to you?

Comment: Thanks but no thank this is works brilliantly. I made a lag function with a sub query but it took ages to complete(probably did something wrong) and the result was not what i was looking for. This runs way better and gives me the results I want. + it's also easier to work with(for me at least)